# mgcv: How to do stepwise regression with a Tweedie response model?

Tags: r, regression, gam, mgcv, tweedie

Does anyone have an idea how to do stepwise regression with Tweedie in R?

I found the `mgcv` package, which apparently treats the power parameter of Tweedie as yet another parameter to be estimated. This seems to improve on having to use `tweedie.profile` to estimate the power outside the `glm`, so it seems encouraging for using an automated stepwise function to do the regression. But I haven't been able to figure out if the package also offers a stepwise function. The package manual has this to say.

I got lost in the talk about smooths:

> There is no step.gam in package mgcv.
>   To facilitate fully automatic model selection the package implements two smooth modification techniques
>   which can be used to allow smooths to be shrunk to zero as part of smoothness selection.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Zheyuan. Yes, very helpful, thanks very much. I need to sit down and understand how this smoothing works. Quick question: does the Tweedie function of mgcv also feature Select = TRUE and Method  = RELM ? Thanks again

Comment: I see that you can either use family=Tweedie in gam, or you can use the Tweedie function. Not sure about their difference yet. That's why I asked if select and method could be used in Tweedie as well. But what you said makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Ah, it's passed to family, got you, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Your question is not specific to "Tweedie" family; it is a general `mgcv` feature in model selection.**

`mgcv` does not use `step.gam` for model selection. I think your confusion comes from another package `gam`, which would use `step.gam` to sequentially add/drop a term and reports AIC. When you go `?step.gam` in `mgcv`, it refers you to `?gam.selection`. `?step.gam` is intentionally left there, in case people search it. But all the details are provided in `?gam.selection`.

**There is no need to do `step.gam` in `mgcv`. Model estimation and model selection are integrated in `mgcv`.** For a penalized regression/smoothing spline, when smoothing parameter goes to infinity (very large), its second derivative is penalized to zero, leaving a simple linear term. For example, if we specify a model like:

```
y ~ s(x1, bs = 'cr') + s(x2, bs = 'cr')
```

while `s(x2)` is a spurious model term and should not be included in the model, then `mgcv:::gam/bam` will shrink `s(x2)` to `x2` after estimation, resulting a model like:

```
y ~ s(x1) + x2
```

This means, when you use `plot.gam()` to inspect the estimated smooth function for each model term, `s(x1)` is a curve, but `s(x2)` is a straight line.

Now this is not entirely satisfying. For a complete, successful model selection, we want to drop `x2` as well, i.e., shrink `s(x2)` to 0, to get notationally a model:

```
y ~ s(x1)
```

But this is not difficult to achieve. We can use shrinkage smooth class `bs = 'ts'` (shrinkage thin plate regression spline, as opposed to the ordinary `tp`) or `bs = cs'` (shrinkage cubic regression spline, as opposed to the ordinary 'cr'), and `mgcv:::gam/bam` should be able to shrink `s(x2)` to 0. The math behind this, is that `mgcv` will modify the eigen values of linear term (i.e., the null space) from 0, to 0.1, a small but positive number, so that penalization takes effect on linear term. As a result, when you do `plot.gam()`, you will see `s(x2)` is a horizontal line at 0.

`bs = 'cs'` or `bs = 'ts'` are supposed to be put in function `s()`; yet `mgcv` also allows you to leave `bs = 'cr'` or `bs = 'tp'` untouched in `s()`, but put `select = TRUE` in `gam()` or `bam()`. The `select = TRUE` is a more general treatment, as shrinkage smooths at the moment only have class `cs` and `ts`, while `select = TRUE` work for all kind of smooth specification. They essentially do the same thing, by increasing 0 eigen values to 0.1.

The following example is taken from the example under `?gam.selection`. Note how `select = TRUE` shrinks several terms to 0, giving an informative model selection.

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(3);n<-200
dat <- gamSim(1,n=n,scale=.15,dist="poisson") ## simulate data
dat$x4 <- runif(n, 0, 1);dat$x5 <- runif(n, 0, 1) ## spurious
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3)+s(x4)+s(x5),data=dat,
        family=poisson,select=TRUE,method="REML")
summary(b)
plot.gam(b,pages=1)
```

[image: shrinkage]

Note that, the `p-values` in `summary.gam()` also gives evidence for such selection:

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
            edf Ref.df  Chi.sq p-value    
s(x0) 1.7655119      9   5.264  0.0397 *  
s(x1) 1.9271039      9  65.356  <2e-16 ***
s(x2) 6.1351372      9 156.204  <2e-16 ***
s(x3) 0.0002618      9   0.000  0.4088    
s(x4) 0.0002766      9   0.000  1.0000    
s(x5) 0.1757146      9   0.195  0.2963    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.545   Deviance explained = 51.6%
-REML = 430.78  Scale est. = 1         n = 200
```

Comment: Zheyuan. Good answer. May I ask for some thoughts please: in your example the coefficients of  x3, x4, (and possible x5??) have been shrunk towards zero, so this is similar to a variable selection?. Would you refit the model without these? (as in my case, if many variables in a model are shrunk to zero then presenting all these zero coefficients in a model would, I  think be problematic with a reviewer.